# Error reading from webservices xml file

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to get a product list for a client from a webservices xml file over to an SQL databse using a little php script, but I can't seem to get it to work.

The relevant code is as follows:

```
$c = 0;  
...
$xml = simplexml_load_file($completeurl);
$listingsArray = $xml->listings->listing;

foreach($listingsArray as $listing){
    $addition[0] = $listing[$c]->type;
    $addition[1] = $listing[$c]->condition;
    //etcetera
    c = c + 1;
}
```

The XML file is formated like:

```
<inventory>
    <listings>
        <listing>
            //tags for type, condition, etc
        </listing>
    </listings>
</inventory>
```

$completeurl is a string that contains the url of the xml file
$addition is an array that's defined earlier in the code

I've been working on this for a while now, but I can't seem to figure out where the error is in my code. The problem that I'm having is that $listingsArray should have close to 100 elements in it, but is constantly coming up with 0. Anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: I tried changing

```
$listingsArray = $xml->listings->listing;
```

to

```
$listingsArray = $xml->listings;
```

But empty strings are still being written to the $addition array. A var_dump of listingsArray show that all of the information is in there, though.

Comment: @cOle2 $c is set to 0 before the foreach loop and iterates with it. Forgot to copy it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing

```
$listingsArray = $xml->listings->listing;
```

to

```
$listingsArray = $xml->listings;
```

Should solve the issue. You set $listingsArray to the array of listings, then the foreach tries to go down another level

Comment: I changed it to that, but it's still not working (though that was a mistake). A var_dump of $listingsArray shows that it's picked up over 100 listings, but attempting to put the listing data into the $addition array still isn't working

Comment: Every time you go through the foreach(), $addition[0] (and [1]) are being overwritten. Should that be $addition[$c][0] instead? The latter seems to make more sense with your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want each listing i believe you are going a child too deep.

`$listingsArray = $xml->listings->listing;`

shoudl be

```
$listingsArray = $xml->listings;

foreach($listingsArray as $listing){
    $addition[0] = $listing[$c]->type;
    $addition[1] = $listing[$c]->condition;
    //etcetera
}
```

additionally what is $c?  It also helps to post your exact errors.  When debugging inserting var_dumps is extremely helpful.  If you think the probelm is `$listingArray`
print it out and see if it contains the data you want.

Comment: $c is a counter that iterates with the foreach loop, so it goes through each of the <listing>'s. I did a var dump and all of the data I need seems to be there, but it's still not writing into the array. I was, however, going one child too deep.